# Android org.webrtc.VideoRenderer.I420Frame arrays from an image

Tags: c#, android, webrtc, android-image, yuv

I keep hoping some code will appear on the internet, but getting nowhere ;)
I am running this [github](https://github.com/kenneththorman/appspotdemo-mono) example.
WebRTC incoming I420Frame object seems to have 3 arrays of yuvPlanes

A typical Android camera app gets PreviewCallback.onPreviewFrame byte[] as a single array of bytes.
My job is to stream an image as I420 at regular interval of time.
Can someone help me in how to generate a I420Frames yuvPlanes from single byte[] array like JPEG/PNG file?

It is pretty critical. All Answers appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`PreviewCallback.onPreviewFrame()` will never return JPEG or PNG stream. You should check your camera [`getSupportedPreviewFormats()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.Parameters.html#getSupportedPreviewFormats()) list *(note that this may differ for front and rear cameras)*. You are guaranteed to have **NV21** in this list. If you are lucky, you can choose **YV12** since API level 12 *(note that some devices, e.g. Amazon Fire HD (2012), lie about this and actually cannot deliver **YV12** stream)*.

It's easy to build a [**I420Frame**](https://chromium.googlesource.com/external/webrtc/+/master/webrtc/sdk/android/api/org/webrtc/VideoRenderer.java#48) from a [**YV12**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/ImageFormat.html#YV12) byte array:

```
private VideoRenderer.I420Frame mFrame;
void onPreviewFrame(byte[] yv12_data, Camera camera) {
    if (mFrame == null) {
        Camera.Parameters params = camera.getParameters(); // this is an expensive call, don't repeat it on every frame!
        assert(params.getPreviewFormat() == ImageFormat.YV12);
        int width = params.getPreviewSize().width;
        int stride_y = 16 + ((width-1)/16)*16;
        int stride_uv = 16 + ((stride_y/2-1)/16)*16;
        int height = params.getPreviewSize().height; 
        mFrame = new VideoRenderer.I420Frame(width, height, 0, new int[]{stride_y, stride_uv, stride_uv}, new ByteBuffer[3], 0);
    }

    mFrame.yuvPlanes[0] = ByteBuffer.wrap(yv12_data, 0, mFrame.yuvStrides[0]*mFrame.height) // Y
    mFrame.yuvPlanes[1] = ByteBuffer.wrap(yv12_data, mFrame.yuvStrides[0]*mFrame.height+mFrame.yuvStrides[2]*mFrame.height/2, mFrame.yuvStrides[1]*mFrame.height/2) // U
    mFrame.yuvPlanes[2] = ByteBuffer.wrap(yv12_data, mFrame.yuvStrides[0]*mFrame.height, mFrame.yuvStrides[2]*mFrame.height/4) // V

    ... do something with the frame
}
```

For [**NV21**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/ImageFormat.html#NV21), you must allocate the U and V planes:

```
private VideoRenderer.I420Frame mFrame;
void onPreviewFrame(byte[] nv21_data, Camera camera) {
    if (mFrame == null) {
        Camera.Parameters params = camera.getParameters(); // this is an expensive call, don't repeat it on every frame!
        assert(params.getPreviewFormat() == ImageFormat.NV21);
        int width = params.getPreviewSize().width;
        int height = params.getPreviewSize().height; 
        mFrame = new VideoRenderer.I420Frame(width, height, 0, new int[]{width, width/2, width/2}, new ByteBuffer[3], 0);
        mFrame.yuvPlanes[1] = ByteBuffer.wrap(new byte[width*height/4]);
        mFrame.yuvPlanes[2] = ByteBuffer.wrap(new byte[width*height/4]);
    }

    mFrame.yuvPlanes[0] = ByteBuffer.wrap(nv21_data, 0, mFrame.width*mFrame.height) // Y
    for (int top=0, from=mFrame.width*mFrame.height; from < mFrame.width*mFrame.height*3/2; to++, from+=2) {
        mframe.yuvPlanes[1][to] = nv21_data[from+1]; // U
        mframe.yuvPlanes[2][to] = nv21_data[from]; // V
    }

    ... do something with the frame
}
```

Comment: Thank you for replying Sir. I got a byte array from an YUV image and I am creating a I420Frame. Now I am getting this error Java.Lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=1179648; regionStart=0; regionLength=2073600 for mFrame.yuvPlanes[0] . How can I make sure irrespective of Image size I should be able to stream it?

Comment: Please provide more details, e.g. stack trace of this exception. Which preview format do you use? Preview size??

Answer (score 0):

```
 I420Frame onPreviewFrame(byte[] yv12_data)
        {
            if (mFrame == null)
            {
                //Camera.Parameters params = camera.getParameters(); // this is an expensive call, don't repeat it on every frame!
                //assert(params.getPreviewFormat() == ImageFormat.YV12);
                int width = 640;
                int stride_y = 16 + ((width - 1) / 16) * 16;
                int stride_uv = 16 + ((stride_y / 2 - 1) / 16) * 16;
                int height = 480;
                mFrame = new VideoRenderer.I420Frame(width, height,  new int[] { stride_y, stride_uv, stride_uv }, new ByteBuffer[3]);
            }                

            mFrame.YuvPlanes[0] = ByteBuffer.Wrap(yv12_data, 0, mFrame.YuvStrides[0] * mFrame.Height); // Y
            mFrame.YuvPlanes[1] = ByteBuffer.Wrap(yv12_data, (mFrame.YuvStrides[0] * mFrame.Height) , mFrame.YuvStrides[1] * mFrame.Height );// U
            mFrame.YuvPlanes[2] = ByteBuffer.Wrap(yv12_data, (mFrame.YuvStrides[0] * mFrame.Height )+ (mFrame.YuvStrides[1] * mFrame.Height), mFrame.YuvStrides[2] * mFrame.Height ); // V
            return mFrame;
            //  ... do something with the frame
        }
```